# Given a finite-duration continuous function $q(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t h(u)\,du$, Could $h(t)$ be discontinuous? Has $h(t)$ to be of compact-supported?

Tags: integration, derivatives, continuity, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Given the **finite-duration continuous** function $q(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t h(u)\,du$,

1. Could $h(t)$ be discontinuous?
2. Is mandatory for $h(t)$ to be a function of compact-support? (so, also of finite-duration?)

Also, since $q(t)$ is bounded $\sup_t|q(t)|<\infty$ because is continuous and compact-supported:

3. Is mandatory for $h(t)$ to be a bounded function? (here a believe that is not a requirement, since there are unbounded functions with finite area, but if (1) and (2) are both affirmative, it will be bounded).

*I have change the term "time-limited" for "finite-duration" since is more accurate and widely used, but it means that the scalar one-variable function $q(t)$ has an starting time $t_s$ for which $q(t) = 0\,\forall t<t_s$, and also an ending time $t_f$ from which $q(t) = 0\,\forall t>t_f$, with $t_s < t_f$*

Comment: In general, integrating makes a signal smoother. So a discontinuous function can become continuous once integrated. For instance, take the Heaviside step function $h(t) = 1$ if $t>0$ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: What is the definition of a time limited function?

Comment: @podiki The difinition I am thinkin of a time-limited function is that it haves a starting point at $t_0$ and a final point at $t_F$ with $t_0<t_F$, so the function have values equal to zero $\forall t<t_0$ and $\forall t>t_F$, or equivalently, is of compact-support with domain $\in [t_0,\,t_F]$

Comment: Try $ t^2 \sin(e^{1/t})$ whose derivative is clearly not bounded nor $L^1_{loc}$.  Multiplying with whatever $C^1_c$ function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a stab at answering 1, guessing at 2, and passing on 3.  If I have any better ideas at a later time I'll add to my answer.

1. Could $h(t)$ be discontinuous?
   Yes, by construction, let:
   $$h(t) = \begin{cases}
       0 & x < 0 \\
       1 & 0 \leq x < 1 \\
       -1 & 1 \leq x < 2 \\
       0 & x \geq 2 
   \end{cases}$$
   $h(t)$ is discontinuous at 0, 1, and 2.
   $$q(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} h(u) \,du $$
   $$q(t) = \begin{cases}
       0 & t < 0 \\
       t & 0 \leq t < 1 \\
       2-t & 1 \leq t < 2 \\
       0 & x \geq 2 
   \end{cases}$$
   $q(t)$ is a continuous function

2. Is mandatory for $h(t)$ to be a function of compact-support?
   I don't have a proof for this, but I suspect this would require a function, that except for finite region is non-zero and yet integrates to zero over any finite interval.  This sounds like it would have to be some sort of pathological function.  I can't think of a suitable one at the moment, but there are some crazy ones...  (maybe the Dirichlet function for the above example except between 0 and 2?)

Is mandatory for $h(t)$ to be a bounded function?